# Data does not update in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-6

I have checked the attributes and all of it matches correctly. I have used this method of updating data in a different Controller and it works fine. It is very weird that only this set of data does not seem to be updated upon running the code. Also, there are no errors popping out, so i don't exactly know how to troubleshoot.

Code in "HawkerInfoController":

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'fname' => ['required'],
            'fid' => ['required'],
            'job' => ['required'],
            'marital' => ['required'],
            'income' => ['required'],
        ]);

        $hawkerAdd = HawkerAdd::find(Auth::user()->user_id);

        $hawkerAdd->hawker_id = Auth::user()->user_id;
        $hawkerAdd->job = $request->input('job');
        $hawkerAdd->marital = $request->input('marital');
        $hawkerAdd->income = $request->input('income');
        $hawkerAdd->picture = $request->input('picture');
        $hawkerAdd->utility_bil = $request->input('bil');
        $hawkerAdd->ty2_inject = $request->input('inject');
        $hawkerAdd->father_name = $request->input('fname');
        $hawkerAdd->father_id = $request->input('fid');

        $hawkerAdd->save();

        return redirect()->route('hawkerInfo.index')->with('success',"Additional Information has been updated");
    }
```

Code in "hawker_info.blade":

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('hawkerInfo.update',Auth::user()->user_id) }}">
  @csrf
  @method('PUT')
    <div class="form-group mb-4">
      <strong><label for="fname">Father's Name</label></strong>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" value="{{$hawkeradd->father_name}}" placeholder="Name" readonly>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-4">
      <strong><label for="fid">Father's Identification Card</label></strong>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fid" name="fid" value="{{$hawkeradd->father_id}}" placeholder="Identification Card" readonly>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group mb-4">
       <strong><label for="job">Occupation</label></strong>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="job" name="job" value="{{$hawkeradd->job}}" placeholder="Your Occupation">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group mb-4">
       <strong><label>Marital Status</label><br></strong>
       <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
         <input type="radio" id="marit1" name="marital" class="custom-control-input" value="Single" {{$hawkeradd->marital == 'Single' ? 'checked' : '' }}>
         <label class="custom-control-label" for="marit1">Single</label>
     </div>
     <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
       <input type="radio" id="marit2" name="marital" class="custom-control-input" value="Married" {{$hawkeradd->marital == 'Married' ? 'checked' : '' }}>
       <label class="custom-control-label" for="marit2">Married</label>
     </div>
     <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
       <input type="radio" id="marit3" name="marital" class="custom-control-input" value="Divorced" {{$hawkeradd->marital == 'Divorced' ? 'checked' : '' }}>
       <label class="custom-control-label" for="marit3">Divorced</label>
     </div>
     <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
       <input type="radio" id="marit4" name="marital" class="custom-control-input" value="Widow" {{$hawkeradd->marital == 'Widow' ? 'checked' : '' }}>
       <label class="custom-control-label" for="marit4">Widow</label>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group mb-4">
       <strong><label for="income">Household Income</label></strong>
       <select id="income" name="income" class="form-control" readonly>
         <option value="Below 1,500" {{$hawkeradd->income == 'Below 1,500' ? 'selected' : '' }}  {{$hawker->income != 'Below 1,500' ? 'disabled' : '' }}>Below 1,500</option>
         <option value="1501 - 2500" {{$hawkeradd->income == '1501 - 2500' ? 'selected' : '' }}  {{$hawker->income != '1501 - 2500' ? 'disabled' : '' }}>1501 - 2500</option>
         <option value="2501 - 3500" {{$hawkeradd->income == '2501 - 3500' ? 'selected' : '' }}  {{$hawker->income != '2501 - 3500' ? 'disabled' : '' }}>2501 - 3500</option>
         <option value="Above 3,501" {{$hawkeradd->income == 'Above 3,501' ? 'selected' : '' }}  {{$hawker->income != 'Above 3,501' ? 'disabled' : '' }}>Above 3,501</option>
       </select>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Update</button>
  </form>
```

Table structure:

```
    Schema::create('hawker_adds', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('hawker_id', 12);
        $table->string('job', 100);
        $table->string('marital', 20);
        $table->string('income', 20);
        $table->string('picture', 50)->nullable();
        $table->string('utility_bil', 50)->nullable();
        $table->string('ty2_inject', 50)->nullable();
        $table->string('father_name', 100);
        $table->string('father_id', 12);

        $table->primary('hawker_id');
        $table->foreign('hawker_id')->references('hawker_id')->on('hawkers')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
```

HawkerAdd Model:

```
protected $primaryKey = "hawker_id";
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'picture', 'job', 'marital', 'income', 'utility_bil', 'ty2_inject', 'father_name', 'father_id',
    ];
```

Comment: why are you finding `HawkerAdd::find(Auth::user()->user_id);` on HawkerAdd, `find()` method used to match a row with its  own primary key

Comment: Please show your table structure.

Comment: Show us `db table` map and `var_dump()` of your `post` request to better assist you.

Comment: And `HawkerAdd Model`

Comment: I have update the table structure and model @SergheiLeonenco

Comment: looks like `route` issue it doesn't call the method you expect, `update` method should have two parameters (`Request $request`, `$id`) the id you send in the form action

Answer (score 0):

To get the update error when `$hawkerAdd->save();`, you can try to catch the exception like this:

```
try{
   $hawkerAdd = HawkerAdd::findOrFail(Auth::user()->user_id);

    $hawkerAdd->hawker_id = Auth::user()->user_id;
    $hawkerAdd->job = $request->input('job');
    $hawkerAdd->marital = $request->input('marital');
    $hawkerAdd->income = $request->input('income');
    $hawkerAdd->picture = $request->input('picture');
    $hawkerAdd->utility_bil = $request->input('bil');
    $hawkerAdd->ty2_inject = $request->input('inject');
    $hawkerAdd->father_name = $request->input('fname');
    $hawkerAdd->father_id = $request->input('fid');

    $hawkerAdd->save();
}
catch(\Exception $e){
   // do task when error
   echo $e->getMessage();   // update query
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Would there be an exception if `$hawkerAdd` is simply `null`?

Comment: It could not be, because he run a validation before to update a DB record. Initially he has to have a record, since he update additional columns.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco i tried the try and catch and did not display any error

Answer (score 0):

Try to name your formfields exactly as the construction of your table. As you haven't done this, we have to work around that. What you try to do is to save an entry that already exists. You want to update.

A bit weird is that your `hawker_id` has exactly the same value as the table `id`. Unless you have renamed the added `protected $primaryKey = 'hawker_id';` in your HawkerAdd model.

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'fname' => ['required'],
            'fid' => ['required'],
            'job' => ['required'],
            'marital' => ['required'],
            'income' => ['required'],
        ]);

        $hawkerAdd = HawkerAdd::find(Auth::user()->user_id);

        $hawkerAdd->update([
            'hawker_id' => Auth::user()->user_id,
            'job' => $request->input('job'),
            'marital' => $request->input('marital'),
            'income' => $request->input('income'),
            'picture' => $request->input('picture'),
            'utility_bil' => $request->input('bil')
            'ty2_inject' => $request->input('inject'),
            'father_name' => $request->input('fname'),
            'father_id' => $request->input('fid'),
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('hawkerInfo.index')->with('success',"Additional Information has been updated");
    }
```

If you call your form input fields exactly like your table fields, you could simply do this:

```
$hawkerAdd = HawkerAdd::find(Auth::user()->user_id);
$hawkerAdd->update($request->all());
```

and that would it be.

Comment: You mean in the same order as the mysql table? @DimitriMostrey

Comment: The order doesn't matter. The names of the fields best match both in the html form elements as the database fields. For simplicity.

Comment: It would help if you posted your `HawkerAdd` model as well. I have to admit I try to fix your issue in the 'dark' as in: we have no idea what's in this table. What did you call the autoincrement field for example. id or hawker_id?

Comment: I tried renaming the fields to match the database fields, and it didn't help. I've posted the HawkerAdd model above. I removed autoincrement fields and replaced it as per the model above. Honestly, thank you for trying to help @DimitriMostrey